# How to change previously pressed UIButton label in UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I have `UITableView` with labels and a button to display list of audios.

Once the button labeled "Play" is pressed it changes to "Stop" and audio is played, and if another button is pressed in other cell the previous cell button SHOULD changes its label to "Play".

Now, **the problem I have here is how to change the previous cell button back to "play" ?**

The labels are outlets in `UITableViewCell` and the `UIButton` is programatically added in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SongTitleCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as SongsTableViewCell

    let songDic : NSDictionary = arrSongs.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as NSDictionary

    cell.lblSongTitle.text = songDic.objectForKey("SongTitle") as? String


    btnPlayPause = UIButton(frame : CGRectMake(13,2,40,40))
    btnPlayPause.tag = indexPath.row
    btnPlayPause.setTitle("Play", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    btnPlayPause.addTarget(self, action: "cellSongClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    cell.contentView.addSubview(btnPlayPause)

    return cell
}
```

The Action of the button here:

```
func cellSongClicked (sender : AnyObject ){
    var remote = GetSongData()
    remote.delegate = self

    var btnCurrentPressed = sender as UIButton

    //Play Selected Song
    let songDic : NSDictionary = arrSongs.objectAtIndex(btnCurrentPressed.tag) as NSDictionary

    if (btnCurrentPressed.currentTitle == "Play") {

      remote.PlaySelectedSong(songDic.objectForKey("SongURL") as String!)
      btnCurrentPressed.setTitle("Stop", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    } else {
      playerContoller.stop()
      btnCurrentPressed.setTitle("Play", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use this strategy:

1) mantain the index path of the cell containing the current playing song in a property of your class (you know the new indexPath from the UIButton tag in the "cellSongClicked" action)

2) In "cellForRowAtIndexPath" set the title of the button to "Play" or "Stop" depending on being this the cell of the current playing song

3) When a button is pressed refresh the current playing song cell and the new playing song cell calling on them "reloadRowsAtIndexPaths"

Hope this helps

**EDIT CODE DETAILS:**

1) don't reallocate every time the button. It must be another outlet of the SongsTableViewCell class (same as the label). And set the target/action from the Interface Builder (add @IBAction in front of "func cellSongClicked" and ctrl-drag from IB)

2) add the following property to your class:

```
private var currentSong : Int?
```

3) method cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SongTitleCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as SongsTableViewCell

    let songDic : NSDictionary = arrSongs.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as NSDictionary

    cell.lblSongTitle.text = songDic.objectForKey("SongTitle") as? String
    cell.btnPlayPause.tag = indexPath.row

    var title : String
    if let _currentSong = currentSong {
        title = indexPath.row == _currentSong ? "Stop" : "Play"
    } else {
        title = "Play"
    }
    cell.btnPlayPause.setTitle(title, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    return cell
}
```

4) And the action:

```
@IBAction func cellSongClicked (sender : AnyObject ){
    var remote = GetSongData()
    remote.delegate = self

    var btnCurrentPressed = sender as UIButton

    //Play Selected Song
    let songDic : NSDictionary = arrSongs.objectAtIndex(btnCurrentPressed.tag) as NSDictionary

    var rowsToReload = [NSIndexPath]()
    var stopCurrent = false
    if let _currentSong = currentSong {
        if btnCurrentPressed.tag == _currentSong {
            stopCurrent = true
        } else {
            rowsToReload.append(NSIndexPath(forRow: _currentSong, inSection:0))
        }
    }
    rowsToReload.append(NSIndexPath(forRow: btnCurrentPressed.tag, inSection:0))
    currentSong = stopCurrent ? nil : btnCurrentPressed.tag
    self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(rowsToReload, withRowAnimation: .None)
}
```

**EDIT: Added stop for current song**

Check if the user is tapping the current playing button (`if btnCurrentPressed.tag == _currentSong`). In that case do not reload that row (otherwise you will reload it twice) and set the currentSong property to nil (using temp boolean stopCurrent).

Comment: Thanks @valfer, I'm kinda confused here, could you please tweak my code where to put your codes...

Comment: I agree -- this is the best solution. But OP, you're currently reusing your cells *and* adding new buttons as subviews for each call to cellForRowAtIndexPath, so that's something you'll have to watch out for especially when you go this route and force reloads.

Comment: Thanks @valfer you are a life saver, very clear, and working like a charm

Comment: @valfer, I'm facing just an small  issue here.. If you press "Stop" in the same cell which is playing, the code crashes in the following line  `self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(rowsToReload, withRowAnimation: .None)`  and gives me this error 'Attempt to create two animations for cell'. Whats is the solution for this? I've tried number of ways and couldn't solve it.!!  Thanks

Comment: Code modified and added description of it in EDIT

Comment: @valfer I've been working on adding a progress view in `cellSongClicked` I couldn't get it working properly. How can I access a progress view added as outlet like how we did for the button?

Comment: You access the outlet progress view (UIProgressView) in the same way of the button (UIButton). If you have more problem consider adding another SO question (SO does not like long comments)